# Value not defined inside defined function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am currently learning python and was just trying a few things out.

```
# Import module
import random
random.seed()

# (Random) values and calculation
firstValue = random.randint(1,10)
secondValue = random.randint(1,10)
sol = firstValue + secondValue

# Define function called in try section of while-loop
def getUserInput():
    print("--- Please solve:", firstValue, "+", secondValue, "---")
    playerSol = input()
    playerSolInt = int(playerSol)

counter = 0
falseAnswer = True

while falseAnswer:
    counter += 1
    try:
       getUserInput()
    except: 
        print("--- You did not enter a number. ---")
        continue

    if sol == playerSolInt:
        print("--- Correct answer! ---")
        falseAnswer = False
    else:
        print("--- False answer! ---")

print("--- You tried", counter, "times in total. ---")
print("*** Program has stopped ***")
```

The function content of getUserInput() primarily was where the function gets called in try:... Now, when I am defining the function it tells me that playerSolInt is not defined. Within the IDE and also when calling the function in the terminal it resolves in an exception. Initializing the variables with 0 at the start of the program did not change anything.

So, what is the matter with it? It probably is something simple I cannot get my head around because of lacking knowledge.

Thank y'all in advance

Comment: `playerSolInt` is only defined locally inside your function `getUserInput()` - that means this variable will only be available inside the function, and not in your global script scope

Comment: if you add the line `return PlayerSolInt` to your `getUserInput()` function. And then write `try: playerSolInt = getUserInput()` in your while loop, it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this tutorial on [Python Scoping](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp).

> A variable created inside a function belongs to the local scope of that function, and can only be used inside that function.

Your `playerSolInt` variable is not available outside the function, so you need to return it from the function and assign it outside.

```py
# Import module
import random
random.seed()

# (Random) values and calculation
firstValue = random.randint(1,10)
secondValue = random.randint(1,10)
sol = firstValue + secondValue

# Define function called in try section of while-loop
def getUserInput():
    print("--- Please solve:", firstValue, "+", secondValue, "---")
    playerSol = input()
    return int(playerSol) # this will return it
    

counter = 0
falseAnswer = True

while falseAnswer:
    counter += 1
    try:
       playerSolInt = getUserInput() # this will assign the returned value
    except: 
        print("--- You did not enter a number. ---")
        continue

    if sol == playerSolInt: 
        print("--- Correct answer! ---")
        falseAnswer = False
    else:
        print("--- False answer! ---")

print("--- You tried", counter, "times in total. ---")
print("*** Program has stopped ***")
```

Comment: Thank you! A colleague of mine suggested the same answer and it worked perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `playerSolInt` is local to your function `getUserInput`. You need to make it global. Below code works:

```
# Import module
import random
random.seed()

# (Random) values and calculation
firstValue = random.randint(1,10)
secondValue = random.randint(1,10)
sol = firstValue + secondValue

# Define function called in try section of while-loop
def getUserInput():
    print("--- Please solve:", firstValue, "+", secondValue, "---")
    playerSol = input()
    global playerSolInt
    playerSolInt = int(playerSol)

counter = 0
falseAnswer = True

while falseAnswer:
    counter += 1
    try:
       getUserInput()
    except: 
        print("--- You did not enter a number. ---")
        continue

    if sol == playerSolInt:
        print("--- Correct answer! ---")
        falseAnswer = False
    else:
        print("--- False answer! ---")

print("--- You tried", counter, "times in total. ---")
print("*** Program has stopped ***")
```